# Ошибка при использовании calendar-telegram

Tags: python, telegram-bot, telegram

[image: Вывод ошибки]

Выдаёт ошибку!!!

```
ERROR - TeleBot: "A request to the Telegram API was unsuccessful. The server returned HTTP 400 Bad Request. Response body: [b'{"ok":false,"error_code":400,"description":"Bad Request: can\'t parse reply keyboard markup JSON object"}']"
https://github.com/unmonoqueteclea/calendar-telegram
```

```py
import telebot
import traceback
import telegramcalendar
import datetime

class Bot:
    """docstring for bot"""
    def __init__(self, token):
        self.server_name="bot"
        self.tg=telebot.TeleBot(token=token)
        self.tg_m=telebot.types
    def sms(self,chat_id,text,parse_mode=None,reply_to_message_id=None,reply_markup=None):
        self.tg.send_message(chat_id=chat_id,text=text,parse_mode=parse_mode,reply_to_message_id=reply_to_message_id,reply_markup=reply_markup)
    def means(self,message):
        message=message
        try:
            Return=message
        except: Return=""
        if Return!="":
            chat_id=message.chat.id
            user_id=message.from_user.id
            message_id=message.message_id
            msg=message.text
            try:
                first_name=message.from_user.first_name
            except:
                first_name=""
            try:
                last_name=" "+message.from_user.last_name
            except:
                last_name=""
            return chat_id, user_id, message_id, first_name, last_name,msg
    def get(self,chat_id):
        r=self.tg.get_chat_members_count(chat_id=chat_id)
        return r
    def photo(self,chat_id,file_id=None,file_size=None,caption=None,parse_mode=None):
        self.tg.send_photo(chat_id=chat_id,photo=file_id,caption=caption,parse_mode=parse_mode)
    def button(self,text=None):
        R=self.tg_m.ReplyKeyboardMarkup(resize_keyboard=True,one_time_keyboard=True)
        R.row('/start','hello')
        return R
    def start(self):
        while True:
            try:                                                            
                @self.tg.message_handler(commands=['start'])
                def answer(message):
                    chat_id, user_id, message_id, first_name, last_name=self.means(message=message)
                    markup=self.button()
                    self.sms(chat_id=chat_id,text="Welcome my master.",reply_markup=markup)                 
                @self.tg.message_handler(commands=['calendar'])
                def calendar_handler(message):
                    chat_id, user_id, message_id, first_name, last_name, msg = self.means(message=message)
                    now = datetime.datetime.now() #Текущая дата
                    date = (now.year,now.month)                 
                    markup = telegramcalendar.create_calendar(now.year,now.month)
                    self.tg.send_message(chat_id=chat_id, text="Пожалуйста, выберите дату",reply_markup=markup)
                @self.tg.message_handler(content_type=["text"])
                def answer_1(message):
                    chat_id, user_id, message_id, first_name, last_name=self.means(message=message)
                    if message.text=='hello':
                        print("123")
                        self.sms(chat_id=chat_id,text="Hi.\nHow are you?")      
                try:
                    self.tg.polling(none_stop=True,interval=0)

                except Exception as e:
                    try:
                        print(traceback.format_exc())
                        self.sms(chat_id="your_telegram_id",text="Error!\n"+traceback.format_exc())
                    except:
                        print(traceback.format_exc())
            except Exception as e:
                try:
                    print(traceback.format_exc())
                    self.sms(chat_id="your_telegram_id",text="Error!\n"+traceback.format_exc())
                except:
                    print(traceback.format_exc())

bot=Bot(token="token")
bot.start()
```

А это `telegramcalendar.ру`

```py
from telegram import InlineKeyboardButton, InlineKeyboardMarkup,ReplyKeyboardRemove
import datetime
import calendar

def create_callback_data(action,year,month,day):
    """ Create the callback data associated to each button"""
    return ";".join([action,str(year),str(month),str(day)])

def separate_callback_data(data):
    """ Separate the callback data"""
    return data.split(";")


def create_calendar(year=None,month=None):
    """
    Create an inline keyboard with the provided year and month
    :param int year: Year to use in the calendar, if None the current year is used.
    :param int month: Month to use in the calendar, if None the current month is used.
    :return: Returns the InlineKeyboardMarkup object with the calendar.
    """
    now = datetime.datetime.now()
    if year == None: year = now.year
    if month == None: month = now.month
    data_ignore = create_callback_data("IGNORE", year, month, 0)
    keyboard = []
    #First row - Month and Year
    row=[]
    row.append(InlineKeyboardButton(calendar.month_name[month]+" "+str(year),callback_data=data_ignore))
    keyboard.append(row)
    #Second row - Week Days
    row=[]
    for day in ["Mo","Tu","We","Th","Fr","Sa","Su"]:
        row.append(InlineKeyboardButton(day,callback_data=data_ignore))
    keyboard.append(row)

    my_calendar = calendar.monthcalendar(year, month)
    for week in my_calendar:
        row=[]
        for day in week:
            if(day==0):
                row.append(InlineKeyboardButton(" ",callback_data=data_ignore))
            else:
                row.append(InlineKeyboardButton(str(day),callback_data=create_callback_data("DAY",year,month,day)))
        keyboard.append(row)
    #Last row - Buttons
    row=[]
    row.append(InlineKeyboardButton("<",callback_data=create_callback_data("PREV-MONTH",year,month,day)))
    row.append(InlineKeyboardButton(" ",callback_data=data_ignore))
    row.append(InlineKeyboardButton(">",callback_data=create_callback_data("NEXT-MONTH",year,month,day)))
    keyboard.append(row)

    return InlineKeyboardMarkup(keyboard)


def process_calendar_selection(bot,update):
    """
    Process the callback_query. This method generates a new calendar if forward or
    backward is pressed. This method should be called inside a CallbackQueryHandler.
    :param telegram.Bot bot: The bot, as provided by the CallbackQueryHandler
    :param telegram.Update update: The update, as provided by the CallbackQueryHandler
    :return: Returns a tuple (Boolean,datetime.datetime), indicating if a date is selected
                and returning the date if so.
    """
    ret_data = (False,None)
    query = update.callback_query
    (action,year,month,day) = separate_callback_data(query.data)
    curr = datetime.datetime(int(year), int(month), 1)
    if action == "IGNORE":
        bot.answer_callback_query(callback_query_id= query.id)
    elif action == "DAY":
        bot.edit_message_text(text=query.message.text,
            chat_id=query.message.chat_id,
            message_id=query.message.message_id
            )
        ret_data = True,datetime.datetime(int(year),int(month),int(day))
    elif action == "PREV-MONTH":
        pre = curr - datetime.timedelta(days=1)
        bot.edit_message_text(text=query.message.text,
            chat_id=query.message.chat_id,
            message_id=query.message.message_id,
            reply_markup=create_calendar(int(pre.year),int(pre.month)))
    elif action == "NEXT-MONTH":
        ne = curr + datetime.timedelta(days=31)
        bot.edit_message_text(text=query.message.text,
            chat_id=query.message.chat_id,
            message_id=query.message.message_id,
            reply_markup=create_calendar(int(ne.year),int(ne.month)))
    else:
        bot.answer_callback_query(callback_query_id= query.id,text="Something went wrong!")
        # UNKNOWN
    return ret_data
```

Comment: После какой команды бот падает?

Comment: @nomnoms12 я добавил фотку, посмотри пожалуйста